# Building a document with text and images from streams

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I would need to display certain images and text in c# WinForms application, so I decided to use WebBrowser. Both images and text are retrieved from the database. However, I don't know how to combine them in the document creation.
Thank you!

Comment: What's the motivation behind that decision? Why not use Label, TextBox, RichTextBox and PictureBox controls?

Comment: There is certain structure so there can be text inbetween images without knowing their count etc., so I think it will be easier to create some kind of HTML document and just display it with webbrowser.

Comment: There is a valid point here - given that you want to pull images from the database it may well be the case that HTML is not an appropriate solution. For a windows application a XAML solution would seem a better bet, either by way of a WPF form or an embedded XPS document.

Comment: Ok. So you are having problems in defining the structure (can't really help you with that) or loading the HTML to the WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 0):

Besides nobugz's suggestion, you can implement IMoniker on an object that exposes your data as mht (web archive) and use IE document's IPersistMoniker interface to load from your object.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx is an example for this interface.
The benefit of using IMoniker over IStream is that you can specify a base URL for your document.