# Problem with image path of html files viewed by webbrowser control

Tags: c#, html, winforms, image, webbrowser-control

I have an webbrowser control on my form. I am able display html files in that control. But my page contains some images if i give **absolute path** to it then images are displayed. But if i give relative path then images are not shown in the pages.

I have HtmlPages folder located at bin folder.

And i am assigning

```
FileStream source = new FileStream(@"..\HtmlPages\supportHtml.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
webBrowser.DocumentStream = source;
```

If i assign `D:\myapp\bin\HtmlPages\file.png` then there is no problem.
My images are stored in same folder. If i open html files with webbrowser then images are displayed.

What is the correct path to set ??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797469/c-webbrowser-building-a-document-with-text-and-images-from-streams

Answer (score 2):

Relative paths are relative to WebBrowser.Url.  Which, when you load the HTML directly, either through DocumentStream or DocumentText is about:blank.  That's not going to help WB find the file, you *must* use an absolute path.  Tinkering with the Url property is not an option.

Consider using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to tinker with the file content before assigning it to the DocumentText property.  Use Path.GetFullPath() to translate relative paths.