# Web Browser Control of Windows Form application not handle relative URL in form action?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, winforms

I have HTML that contains a form with a relative URL in the `action`, which is not working.

But when is uses a full URL it works fine.

So is there any property to set in the `WebBrowser` control for Windows Application?

**Not Working Code:**

```
form method="post" action="/_abc/xyz?re_url=kn" id="formSubmit"
```

**Working Code:**

```
form method="post" action="https://somesite.local/_abc/xyz?re_url=kn" id="formSubmit"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682091/problem-with-image-path-of-html-files-viewed-by-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 1):

the WinForms WebBrowser control relies on an old version of Internet Explorer, the problem with that is that the browser will be very slow, unresponsive at times, or not up to standards as it's been killed by Microsoft in favour of the new Chromium-based Edge.

They have a control that works both for WinForms, WPF and UWP.

It's called [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) and is simple to get started with, all you need is in the [getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) present on Microsoft's website.

Another option is [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/), it's also chromium based and offers a bit more for the touchscreen side, but generally both are a good option. The Wiki you can find [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/). The Quick Start guide is also helpful and can be found [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start).

Both are also Open-Source controls.

If you would like to use a Gecko-based browser (eg. Firefox's engine) you can use [GeckoFx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GeckoFX). I couldn't find a documentation for it but I found [this](https://nhabuiduc.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/geckofx-net-webbrowser-setup-and-features/) helpful guide that can get you started. There are many tutorials available however that you can use.

If you want to keep the current browser, I am sure you will run into more problems than switching to another control.

I have found [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/707c5901-5f5d-487a-bedc-ca47ca00523c/webbrowser-control-and-relative-img-paths) on MSDN that talks about relative image paths, which is almost the same problem as here just that it's a url of a website. This is fixed in WebView2, CefSharp and GeckoFx as they use up to date standards, you could fiddle with the code from the post, but It's unlikely that you will find it an optimal solution for a simple request.